# Asked for credentials when sending GET request for Applicationinsights REST API

Tags: rest, azure, postman, azure-application-insights

This is the GET request I send

```
api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/DEMO_APP/metrics/metadata?x-api-key=DEMO_KEY
```

but all I get back is an Access Denied, stating that my Credentials could not be verified as they are missing.

Answer (score 0):

The query parameter should be `api_key` as specified in the docs, not `x-api-key`:

> Pass the API key via an X-Api-Key custom header or an api_key query parameter.

As mentioned, you can use X-Api-Key header instead of a query parameter too.

Comment: I did that, i took the wrong example but if i don't i get a request error, if i do this correctly i still get the Access denied